# Dropdown for a lookup edit control

Tags: html, vb.net, autocomplete

i am using a third party tool "lookupedit control" which is similar to a combobox. as we type in the address bar of our browser we get the related items in the dropdown of the address bar. eg: if e type go we get all the items starting from go in the drop down of the address bar. I want to implement the same functionality for lookupedit or a combobox. can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the jquery plugin autocomplete. check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Please explain your solution rather than just providing a link.